# JavaScript: Get Element Where Attribute StartsWith Value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes

**JavaScript: Get Element Where Attribute StartsWith Value**

Using pure **JavaScript**, how to search for a particular DOM Element using **Attribute and Value**?
Using the **Start of the Attribute-Value** as a search parameter which is a String.

*Example:*
How to get the following DOM element using pure JavaScript? The `Random_URL_value` value changes everytime, which is what I want to obtain.

```
<div style="background-image: url(Random_URL_value);"></div>
```

The query must be like: **Get Element Where Attribute StartsWith Value**

Perhaps, using `.querySelectorAll` or `.querySelector`

Thank you.

Comment: The latest version of the draft selectors API is here: [*https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/). There is a section for [*Substring matching attribute selectors*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-substrings) with examples that should suit.

Answer (score 3):

Ya, you can use either **querySelector()** or **querySelectorAll()**

```js
document.querySelector("div[style^=back]").classList.add("highlight");
```

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  float: left;
}

div.highlight{
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100);"></div>
<div></div>
```